# python file object how to remove byte from current seed postion to end

Tags: python, file

python file object how to remove byte from current seed postion to end

`f = open(filename, "a+")`

`truncate_pos = f.tell()`

`f.truncate(truncate_pos)`

seems not work,how could i do?

Comment: What does "remove byte from current seed postion to end" mean?

Comment: it means delete from current postion to the end of file.

Comment: in what way does it not work?

Comment: object after truncate_pos still exist

Comment: You say *seed* all the time, don't you mean [seek](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#file.seek)?

Answer (score 2):

Opening a file in `a+` positions the pointer at the end of the file; truncation from there results in no change to the file.

Comment: there is some other operate . i use seed(0) to start of the file ,and write some byte,and now i want to delete from current postion to end

Comment: @kikyou You can't write to the beginning of a file in python, the `.write()` method writes to the end. Secondly, the `.truncate()` expects a size argument, and you're giving it the position of the last byte in the file, of course there's no change.

Comment: You can, but not in `a` or `a+`.